# Number of degrees of freedom of two particles connected by a rigid rod moving freely in a plane is?

Tags: classical-mechanics

Hi respected researchers and scholars,

I have a question regading degrees of freedom

Number of degrees of freedom of two particles connected by a rigid rod moving freely in a plane is _______ ?

I have in my mind is: For a single particle it is 2 in a plane,

Q. 1  What if two or three independent particles in a plane? Is it 4

Q. 2  if two particles connected by a rigid rod moving freely in a plane ?

Need your kind attention. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Three real parameters, 2 for center of mass of whole thing, one for rotation angle would do it. Don't know if that's what you mean by degree of freedom...

Comment: is it right to say one for x-axis, one for y axis and one for rotation?

Comment: @Taj Yes, since $x,y$ would specify center of mass.

Answer (score 1):

Think of DOF as the number of parameters to completely define the position of the particles

You need two parameter for the first particle, the $x$ and $y$ coordinate.

After specifying the position of the first particle, then specify the angle of the rigid rod.

Thus 3 DOF in total